# Showing a different tab with an if statement on Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

Ionic 2 seems very different from 1. I used the starter project and those are my files:

Tabs.html

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="Home" tabIcon="home"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Tabs.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { SigninPage } from '../Auth/Signin/Signin';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'Tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root: any = SigninPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from 'ionic-native';

import { TabsPage } from '../pages/Tabs/Tabs';

@Component({
    template: `<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>`
})
export class MyApp {
    rootPage = TabsPage;

    constructor(platform: Platform) {
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any way to show a different tab with an if condition? For example, I want to show `Tabs.App.html` or `Tabs.Auth.html` depending on an if block.

What is the best way to do it with Ionic 2?

Answer (score 0):

In ionic2 every page is accompanied by it's `.ts` file. So if you want 2 tabs, `app.html` and `auth.html` you would need to create both these pages and their `.ts` file.

In that way you can write an if-statement saying:

```
if(1 > 2){
  this.rootpage = AuthTab;
}else{
  this.rootpage = AppTab;
}
```

**ps don't forget to import your components**

Comment: Where do I define this logic? In `app.components.ts`?

Comment: Thage page where you set all the tabs. Probably `app.component`, not sure about your setup

Comment: I guess I have to do something like this for Ionic 2. `$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", (event, toState)`. Is there any way to do it? Basically I have to listen for state change events on `app.components.ts`, and if the target state starts with "Auth", I can set this.rootPage to AuthTab, otherwise to AppTab. What is the new way to listen state change events?